# Angular CLI local environment allowing external connections

Tags: angular-cli, development-environment, angular-cli-v6

Right now in my application I use various evironment settings, including `dev` one:

```
// environment.dev.ts
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    maintenanceMode: false
};
```

However, it is not possible to use my local application instance from anywhere except my machine. **I'd like my local application instance to work from any computer** (for example, in my local network).

Frontend is working fine (i start it with `ng serve -c dev --host 0.0.0.0`), but it's using `localhost` backend (which does not work anywhere but my machine).

I tried changing apiURL to `0.0.0.0`, but this causes javascript error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`.

It is possibile to make it running when I enter my local network IP in `apiURL`, but it won't work when my IP will change. Is there any universal solution?

Comment: `ng serve` is not meant to let you server your application to others, its meant for dev-time serving of the application. If you want others to use the application, serve it with a web server like nginx, or IIS.

Comment: @R.Richards Sure, I know. That's not meant to be production server. But still, that's useful scenario.

Comment: It's not meant to serve an application that can be accessed outside of your dev machine either, production or otherwise. Try something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).